# SSMS2012 Help going to Chrome rather than MSIE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, ssms, sql-server-2012

Running Win7 Ent 64bit

From within SSMS 2012 SP2, when I hit F1 (or `Help`, `View Help`), I am taken to Google Chrome rather than MSIE11. By every indication I can find, MSIE11 is my default browser, not Google Chrome.

I've gone into MSIE11 and made it my default (`Tools`, `Internet Options`, `Programs`, `Make Default`). Then into Chrome, check `Settings`, and it tells me `Google Chrome is not currently your default browser`. For good measure, I went into Firefox, `Tools`, `Options`, to see `Firefox is not your default browser`.

In `Control Panel`, `Set your default programs`, `Internet Explorer`, I see `This program has all its defaults`. For good measure, I select `Choose defaults for this program`, click `Select All`, and click `Save`.

I've gone fishing around the registry to try to see where Chrome has left it's toehold, and won't give it up to MSIE11, but I'm not finding it.

**Update Aug 15, 2015**

I discovered a nuance to this issue. This problem occurs only when I'm running SSMS under different credentials using Runas. If I run SSMS under the AD credentials I'm logged in as, F1 correctly takes me to MSIE.